# Show Small Preview Picture in Access 2013 List Box On Click

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database with a table that stores a bunch of files. I've created a form to search for the files by various key words. After searching, the results are displayed in a listbox - coded in VBA. If I double click on a specific result, it opens the file's path (say a PDF document). I want to make it so that if I click just once on the specific result, it will show a little picture in the corner of the form. How would I go about coding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the path name is a url to a file or web site (or document on a web site), or some document on your local computer?

Assuming that the list box sql source is say 3 columns,

Id    Description   FullPathName

Likely in above, while the list box may well be based on 3 columns, you can hide the id and FullPathName of the query used to drive the list box.

Next up simply drop a web control in the upper corner and size it the way you want (a web control is ideal, since it will display picture, web sites, PDF, word documents and just about anything else your computer can render).

Then in the after update even of the list box, use this VBA code:

```
  Private Sub List0_AfterUpdate()

     Dim s       As String

     s = "=(" & """" & Me.List0.Column(2) & """" & ")"

     Me.WebBrowser2.ControlSource = s

  End Sub
```

Comment: Ok that worked perfectly for me. However, do you know how I would go about shrinking image sizes to fit the size of the box? Right now there are scroll bars and the image size is very big. Is there a way to make it show the images to shrink to fit?

Comment: I don’t believe that is possible. You are rendering a word document, a PDF document, maybe a JPG, maybe an Excel sheet, maybe a web site. That web control can display anything and technology to figure out what kind of document is being rendered from a pdf to power point presentation and THEN FIGURE out how to scale that given application likely does not exist in the software industry.

Comment: if you limit the display to say JPG and maybe PDF, then you could test for the type of document and use software to pull the first page of the PDF and convert into a image. The KEY concept here is  you need to put some LIMITS on your question. Having the ability to display near any kind of document on the form is great, but then that quite much eliminates the practical ability to re-size that display. If you limited only to say picture type files, then re-sizing is quite easy.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with an image control and not a web browser? If I have an image path stored in my table, can I just use an image control instead of a web browser control?

Comment: That will work for pictures, but not PDF and word files. The picture box has options to re-size to fit. (so, yes, if you limited to pictures this can work)