# Access display image in a listbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query with an url to an specific image.

I would like to display that image in a listbox where i display the rest of the data of that record, but I do not know if it's even possible.

I found this: [Show Small Preview Picture in Access 2013 List Box On Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573419/show-small-preview-picture-in-access-2013-list-box-on-click)

but it does nothing.

Could you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cannot display images in a listbox.

Comment: Could us a subform.